# Dual Monitor Setup not working

Tags: office365

I have the same setup at home as I do at the office, an HP laptop which connects to 2 x Samsung monitors via a docking station. Its the same laptop used at home and in the office. Although different monitors they are identical make & model. Although different docking stations they are identical make & model.
For both office and home setups, one monitor is connected with a blue ended Analog VGA cable plugged directly into the monitor and docking station. The other monitor is connected with a white DVI cable plugged directly into the monitor and a DVI display port adapter which then plugs directly into the docking station.
All works fine at the office - no issues!
At home the monitor using the blue VGA cable works fine.
However the monitor using the DVI cable displays 'TEST GOOD' followed by 'CHECK SIGNAL CABLE (RED-GREEN-BLUE) ANALOG'. I have swapped cables over and the functioning monitor follows suit ie VGA connected monitor good, DVI not.
This tells me the issue is not the monitors.
I took the DVI cable to the office and swapped them over. The office setup still worked fine. This tells me the cable is not the issue.
I brought the office cable home and still have the same issue ie the DVI connected monitor will not work.
The laptop setup isn't the issue as all works fine at the office.
Do you have any idea as to what may be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like your docking station is the culprit. Have you tried connecting your monitors directly to the computer?

Comment: Click Win menu > Settings > Display, check whether the monitor connected by DVI interface could be correctly identified. If yes, press Win + P, choose Exten or other mode for a test. Besides, check the related drives. If not, you may swap the docking stations. The power supply may be insufficient, the device may be incompatible and etc.

Answer (score 0):

On the monitor at home connected via DVI cable, try using the buttons on the monitor to select a different input.